# Linked List: Copy List Using Recursive

Tags: recursion, linked-list

I am new to Linked List. I am trying to write a CopyList() code that can copy a linked list to a new list. There's a unique version using recursive and I don't really understand:

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node* CopyList(struct node* head) {
   struct node* current = head;

   if (current == NULL) return NULL;
   else {
      struct node* newList = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
      newList->data = current->data;
      newList->next = CopyList(current->next); // recur for the rest
      return(newList);
   }
}
```

My trouble of understanding is the line newList->next = CopyList(current->next);
So how does this work for copying and why?

Comment: First! change current to head. current is defined nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

Lets take an example. If you simply put the current->next in newList->next
i.e

newList->next = current->next. Then it will point to the next node of old list only. Not to the next node of new list. 
So to make a different list (Copy list). You separately have to make a new node and return it to point to next of previous node.

Answer (score 1):

This is the magical recursive statement.

## newList->next = CopyList(current->next);

For each recursive step, this will **delegate the task of creating remaining linked list**, to the next recursive call.

For example: List is getting created from right to left.

```
CopyList (1->2->3->4->5)
|
|---------1-> CopyList (2->3->4->5)
              |
              |---------2-> CopyList (3->4->5)
                            |
                            |---------3-> CopyList (4->5)
                                          |
                                          |---------4-> CopyList (5)
                                                        |
                                                        |---------5-> CopyList (NULL)

                                                                  Returns 5
                                                    Returns 4->5->NULL
                                      Returns 3->4->5->NULL
                         Returns 2->3->4->5->NULL
           Returns 1->2->3->4->5->NULL
```

As per wiki

1. > A simple base case (or cases)—a terminating scenario that does not use recursion to produce an answer.
2. > A set of rules that reduce all other cases toward the base case.

   In your case, terminating scenario is if list reaches the end, just return null and a new node is created at every step that leads the list to the base scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is the recursion step.  The previous two commands create a new node and copy the head of the **current** list to that object.  Now, instead of iterating (looping) through the rest of the list, we call **CopyList** to copy the *remainder* of the list -- everything *except* the head node that we just copied.

**CopyList** returns a copy of that remainder, which we simply append to the copy of the head node ... and we're done.